# Remove "0" from number of time in R

Tags: r, date, datetime, time

I've tried to research the web about this question, but I did not found it.

I want to change my time format from `"07/08/2014 09:18"` to `"07/08/2014 9:18"` I do not want any "0" in the front of number of time(hour).

Note: I work using R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `format()` or `strftime()` with a format string that specifies "%k" for the hour:

```
x <- "07/08/2014 09:18"
z <- as.POSIXct(x, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
format(z, format="%d/%m/%Y %k:%M")
[1] "07/08/2014  9:18"
```

You can find the complete list of formatting strings in the help for `?strftime`

Comment: I think you mean `strptime()`.

Comment: @Pascal `strftime()` and `strptime()` perform different operations.

Comment: Correct, I did a mistake when I searched that function. Sorry for annoyance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sub`

```
sub(' 0', ' ', x)
#[1] "07/08/2014 9:18"  "07/08/2014 10:20"
```

#### data

```
  x <- c("07/08/2014 09:18", "07/08/2014 10:20")
```